# MVC 4, Can't get the claims added on registration unless log in again

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using asp.net mvc 4. When a user registers, I'm adding 3 claims (Firstname, Lastname, Displayname). The claims are added correctly and I can check them in the database.

However when I want to get the claims like this:

```
ClaimsPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User;
Displayname = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Displayname").Value;
```

I get a `NullReferenceException` and checking the claims value, I see that my added claims aren't fetched.

However if I logout and login again, these claims are also fetched. What should I do that claims added on registration, gets added to the authenticated user for the first time?

Here is how I add the claims:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Username, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
            await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("Firstname", model.Firstname));
            await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("Lastname", model.Lastname));
            await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("Displayname", $"{model.Firstname} {model.Lastname}"));
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling those two lines of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.

the problem is that I add the claims after Signing in:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("Firstname", model.Firstname));
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("Lastname", model.Lastname));
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("Displayname", $"{model.Firstname} {model.Lastname}"));
```

Changing the code to this solved the problem:

```
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("Firstname", model.Firstname));
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("Lastname", model.Lastname));
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim("Displayname", $"{model.Firstname} {model.Lastname}"));
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
```

Comment: Just so the behaviour is understood, the claims are available once once you leave the current controller action and enter another.